# How to assign a data to Session from select query

Tags: php, session

This is my code

```
if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='".$_POST['username']."' AND passcode='".$_POST['password']."'";
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) >0) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['username2'] = "gfgf";
            $_SESSION['username3'] = $row['column_name'];
            $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
            header('location: index.php');
        }else {
            array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
        }
    }
```

I want to use `$_SESSION['username3']` .But it is not work. what is the problem with my code. `$_SESSION['username2']` is finely work.
there is a matching data in this Table too.

Comment: What is  `$username`? Have you started the session?

Comment: Also, please **DO NOT** use `md5()` for storing passwords - use `password_hash()`/`password_verify()`. Your current setup uses *plaintext passwords*, which is ***really bad***. And learn how to use prepared statements.

Comment: $username in place to $_POST['username']

Comment: @Qirel  It is about login form. And it work finely. username is from login.php and this is the code of server.php. After login it is successfully mention "Welcom [username]" in index.php.  now I want another row of his contact number behind him. it also in above "admin table".

Comment: But you have not defined `$username` anywhere in that code.

Comment: @SanjitBhardwaj  No problem with username. I want assign a data from the table.

Comment: session_start();
 $username = "";
 $accountno = "";
 $gsmno = "";
 $email    = "";
 $errors = array(); 
 $_SESSION['success'] = "";
 
 $db = mysqli_connect("sssssss", "ssss", "ssss", "ssss");

 
 if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);
  if (empty($username)) {
   array_push($errors, "Username is required");
  }
  if (empty($password)) {
   array_push($errors, "Password is required");
  }

@Qirel  here is the part of above

Comment: @Qirel
Thank you for your cooperation sir. problem solved. answered by  below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. You missed this line `while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc())` and `$password = md5($_POST['password']);`

```
if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='".$_POST['username']."' AND passcode='".$_POST['password']."'";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) >0) {
        while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['username2'] = "gfgf";
            $_SESSION['username3'] = $row['column_name'];
            $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
            header('location: index.php');
        }
    }else {
        array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
    }
}
```